# How to process form with php & ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How to process form with php & ajax?

html:

> ```
> <form>
>  <input type="radio" value="1" />
>  <input type="radio" value="2" />
>  <input type="radio" value="3" />
>  <input type="radio" value="4" />
>  <input type="button" id="go" value="go"/>
> </form>
> ```

How to collect value from radio, then submit it in php `$value='';` and show to user this value after clicking button `#go`?

I want to make simple form. User chooses value from form, then clicks on button. This value will be shown to user instantly and it will be adds to mysql database.

Comment: You've already answered your question: Use AJAX. Simplest method to do that is to use jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: There are several AJAX libraries out there that can do this, including, but not limited to, jQuery, prototype, Dojo and MooTools.  I suggest you research their APIs and use the one you feel most comfortable with.  Incidentally, you really ought to give a name to your group of radio buttons, otherwise they won't be mutually exclusive, and to conform with [the W3C spec on radio buttons](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#radio), you should set one of them to be checked by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the HTML, don't forget to give the radio buttons a `name` attribute.

```
<form id="form">
  <input type="radio" value="1" name="my_radio" />
  <input type="radio" value="2" name="my_radio"  />
  <input type="radio" value="3" name="my_radio" />
  <input type="radio" value="4" name="my_radio" />
  <input type="button" id="go" value="go"/>
</form>
```

For the Javsacript, specify **your** file instead of `file.php`

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
   $.post('file.php', { $(this).serialize() }, function( data ) { 
     alert( data.radio_value ); 
   })
});
```

For the PHP

```
if( isset( $_POST['my_radio'] ) )
{
   echo json_encode( array('radio_value' => $_POST['my_radio'] ) ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set name the name for the radio buttons.

```
<form id="foo">
 <input type="radio" value="1" name="bar"/>
 <input type="radio" value="2" name="bar"/>
 <input type="radio" value="3" name="bar"/>
 <input type="radio" value="4" name="bar"/>
 <input type="button" id="go" value="go"/>
</form>
```

If you can use jQuery then you can use this code:

```
$('#go').click(function() {
    $.post('script.php', $('#foo').serialize(), function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

and in php

```
<?php
// connect to database
$bar = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bar']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (bar) VALUES ('$bar')");
echo $bar;
?>
```

Comment: But if i have several #foo (foo1, foo2, foo3) forms, how to collect all values and summ it?  (it's only digits values)

Comment: Why you want to use several forms if you have one submit? Use one form and put all radios and other form elements into it. If you must you can use this `$('#foo1, #foo2, #foo3').serialize()` and it will return values from all forms.